# unix-odbc package, undefined reference to SQLCancelHandle

Tags: 16.04, package-management, bug-reporting, odbc

I am trying to compile a **ODBC** software with the `unix-odbc` library which I installed with the following command on **Ubuntu 16.04**.

```
apt-get install unixodbc-dev unixodbc-bin unixodbc
```

The library worked fine until I tried to call `SQLCancelHandle` in my software. And I started to get:

```
error: undefined reference to 'SQLCancelHandle'
```

After investigation, I realized that in `sql.h` the function was defined in the package. (call with the wrong parameters issue into an error of compilation complaining about the parameters)

My conclusion is the shared library associated with doesn't implement the function.

**Question:** Where am I supposed to put issue about Ubuntu packages? Is it possible to suggest a fix?

Comment: [You can file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) You should completely describe the problem. Though you shouldn't *only* give your analysis of what caused it and your fix, you can definitely include a fix, or suggest how it should be fixed, or both, in your bug report. We also have [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121) I don't think you really need any more specific information than those resources give, but if you do, please clarify (you should **[edit]**, and feel free also to comment with `@EliahKagan` in the comment, which will ping me).

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for your help. I can't report as a bug as it is a `-dev` package.  But I will try the newest `.deb` file to verify the bug has been corrected and suggest an update for the package.

Comment: You can report bugs in software provided by `-dev` packages. Bugs are reported against source packages. A source package typically has at least one associated binary package, but often has more than one. Even `-dev` packages that don't provide "binaries" are still binary packages in this sense, and [the `unixodbc-dev` binary package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/unixodbc-dev) is built from [the `unixodbc` source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unixodbc). You can therefore report the bug against `unixodbc` in Ubuntu, if it is present in the `unixodbc-dev` binary package.

Comment: You can even use `ubuntu-bug` with `-dev` packages: `ubuntu-bug unixodbc-dev`. [Apport collects details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPT2F.png) and [gives you a browser tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZzoR.png), which [turns to a page where you can report the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Eoe.png). **Can you [edit] your question with the info from your comment about not being able to report against a `-dev` package?** That's different enough from the linked question that I think this isn't really a dupe. Then we can reopen this and I (or someone else if they do it first) can post an answer.